# Angular Router and navigation via 'backward' 'forward' browser buttons

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a standard Angular app which uses the Angular Router to control page navigation.

If I control navigation via a code like this

```
this.router.navigate(['component2']);
```

the correct page is shown but in the browser 'address bar' we find something like ***https://myserver.com/component2***

Since I do not want to see ***component2*** as the last part of the url, I use the following code to navigate

```
this.router.navigate(['component2'], {skipLocationChange: true})
```

If I do this though, the navigation via the standard 'backward' 'forward' buttons of the browser does not work any more.

Is there a way to avoid having the reference of the path to the component as part of the url and, at the same time, be able to navigate via standard browser buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume not. As described in the docs here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html the Angular router uses the address bar as part of its standard operations.

I can understand why you would not want to display the names of the components in the address bar. Why not change the route path names to the feature? like: myserver.com/customers or myserver.com/products.

Trying to fight the standard way the router works may lead your team down a difficult path.